# Why can't I call template class's function in declaration line?

Tags: c++

In my class assignment, I got a function call in the declaration line of a template class.

test.h

```
template <typename T, char N, char C, typename K>
class MyClass
{
    public:
    static const char* Get()
    {
    }
};

template <char N, char C>
class MyClass<std::string, N, C, char>
{
    private:
        std::string x;
    public:
    
    void setX(size_t t){
        x.resize(t);
    }
    
    void operator()(std::string y){
        setX(y.size());
        for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < y.size(); i++) {
            x[i] = y[i];
        }
    }
    
    void print(){
        for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++){
            std::cout << x[i];
        }
    }
};
```

test.cpp

```
int main(){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Hello";
    MyClass<std::string, ' ', '*', char> tn( ss.str() ); <---- "This is where I got the error"
    tn.print();
};
```

I got a **no matching function for call** error, but if I do it like in the following, I got no error:

```
int main(){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Hello";
    MyClass<std::string, ' ', '*', char> tn;
    tn( ss.str() );
    tn.print();
};
```

Edit:
Here is the complete error output:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:15:52: error: no matching function for call to 'MyClass<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, ' ', '*', char>::MyClass(std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type)'
  MyClass<std::string, ' ', '*', char> tn( ss.str() );
                                                    ^
In file included from test.cpp:4:0:
test.h:17:7: note: candidate: MyClass<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, ' ', '*', char>::MyClass()
 class MyClass<std::string, N, C, char>
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.h:17:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
test.h:17:7: note: candidate: MyClass<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, ' ', '*', char>::MyClass(const MyClass<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, ' ', '*', char>&)
test.h:17:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const MyClass<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, ' ', '*', char>&'
test.h:17:7: note: candidate: MyClass<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, ' ', '*', char>::MyClass(MyClass<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, ' ', '*', char>&&)
test.h:17:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'MyClass<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, ' ', '*', char>&&'
```

Comment: You need to construct the object before you can use the `operator()` - in the first sample the compiler sees it as you trying to call a non-existing constructor with an `std::string` argument

Comment: Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output (as text) into your question.

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with templates. You'd get the same error if `MyClass` was not a template.
This

```
MyClass<std::string, ' ', '*', char> tn( ss.str() );
```

calls the constructor. `MyClass<std::string,' ','*',char>` has no matching constructor, hence the error.

This works for temporaries:

```
MyClass<std::string, ' ', '*', char>{}.operator()( ss.str() );
```

If you want to squezee everything in a single line, you could make `operator()` return a reference to `*this`. However, code does not get more readable by squeezing everything in a single line of code.

---

PS: The method mentioned in the error, eg here:

```
 candidate: MyClass<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, ' ', '*', char>::MyClass()
```

is not `MyClass::operator()`. It is the constructor. If you cannot modify `main` you need to provide a constructor that takes a string as parameter. This is what the compiler is looking for when it complains here:

```
test.cpp:15:52: error: no matching function for call to 'MyClass<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, ' ', '*', char>::MyClass(std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type)'
  MyClass<std::string, ' ', '*', char> tn( ss.str() );
                                                    ^
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, and I wouldn't do it like that, but my teacher wrote the .cpp file, and I can't change it's content, so I have to make it work somehow.

Comment: @robotorg If you're not allowed to modify the `main` function, perhaps you should update the class template specialization to have a suitable constructor?

Comment: @robotorg you should make such requirements clear in the question. You asked "Why?" and this answer does explain that (i hope). The fix is to write a matching constructor

Comment: @robotorg actually I am a little confused. You even present an alternative that works and seem to ask about the difference. If you "know" that the non working code attempts to call a constructor, then I don't understand the question

Comment: @robotorg they mean: The `main` you were given is calling a constructor not an `operator()`. If you provide such constructor then the code will compile

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thank you for sticking with me, I finally get it.